# Strongloop Passport.js authentication - "Failed to obtain access token"

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, passport.js, loopbackjs

I'm trying to write an Express/Passport app that authenticates with a Github Enterprise server. This has required manually-editing the github-strategy for passport to point to the private enterprise API endpoints. No biggie there.

I'm using Strongloop to build the application, so I'm using the `strongloop-passport-component` integration.

As far as I can tell the app is configured properly, but on redirect, I get the following error message:

> Loopback 500 InternalOAuthError: Failed to obtain access token    at
>   Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError
>   (/Users/Tom/Desktop/soundoff/node_modules/passport-github/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:370:17)
>   at
>   /Users/Tom/Desktop/soundoff/node_modules/passport-github/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:166:45
>   at
>   /Users/Tom/Desktop/soundoff/node_modules/passport-github/lib/strategy.js:75:25
>   at
>   /Users/Tom/Desktop/soundoff/node_modules/passport-github/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:177:18
>   at ClientRequest.
>   (/Users/Tom/Desktop/soundoff/node_modules/passport-github/node_modules/passport-oauth2/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:148:5)
>   at emitOne (events.js:90:13)    at ClientRequest.emit
>   (events.js:182:7)    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener
>   (_http_client.js:262:9)    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)    at
>   TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:7)

If I look at the github app settings, I can verify that the user successfully authenticated with the app. It just seems to fail to redirect the user to the redirect URI. aparrently it cannot find the access token?

The URL the user ends up on is something like `http://0.0.0.0:3000/auth/github/callback?code=dceef2ffe07b5dbfa194` -- however, I expect them to end up on `http://0.0.0.0:3000/auth/account`.

What could be causing Loopback to not find the access token? Isn't it in the url `?code=`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was to not use strongloop-passport-component, unfortunately. Developer has been unresponsive and doesn't look like this will be fixed.

Comment: Any chance you could provide guidance as to how/where you plugged passport into loopback? About to do something very similar, so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It can fail to obtain the access token if the temporary token (here, `dceef2ffe07b5dbfa194`) is not valid.

It is possible that in your modified github-strategy, the second phase of the OAuth flow where the temporary token is exchanged for a final token, is not configured properly, most likely requesting main github api instead of your enterprise github api for token exchange

Comment: Hey thanks for your help... doesn't seem to be it though. I've updated all the references to github to point to my enterprise domain. :(

Comment: Ok, then I would recommend to not use the strongloop-passport-component. I've run into similar issues with it, unreliable behavior, and the fact that it encapsulates passport makes debugging hard. Also, this component does not seem well maintained given the activity on github repository. Using directly passport js was rather straightforward, and lets you understand what is going on under the hood.

Comment: Thanks @Overdrivr. I'll probably do that. A shame since I liked how the module was set up but if it doesn't work, it doesn't work! In the mean time I've requested them to provide a demo with github integration, maybe they'll fix it up down the line. Thanks

Comment: I have _exactly_ the same error with plain express.js. (But works with loopback *scratches head*)

Comment: Ok, I know now what I did wrong. Just for other fellows: First of all, this error is produced by old code, use newer versions. Just using newer versions didn't fix it for me, double checking the `client-id` and `client-secret` made it magically work!  ;)